# Replace value if exists in another query(table)?

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying something totally new (for me). I have a PHP file where I try to retrieve the data of 2 tables and replace values if they match. Since I'm not really sure what I'm doing I'm kinda stuck:) Here is what i want:
I have 2 tables in my mysql database.

The table 'advertisement' has the column 'logo_fid'.
The table 'files' has the columns 'fid' and 'filepath'.

Now I would like to `echo` the values of the 'logo_fid' column in the 'advertisement' table.
Before that, however, I would like to see if in the table 'files' a corresponding value is stored in the 'fid' volumn and if so I would like to echo the value of 'filepath' instead of the value of 'logo_fid'.
So basically what I want is to replace the returned value of the logo_fid column, if this value matches with the value in the 'fid' column, with the corresponding 'filepath' value.

Hope I made myself clear. Anyway I have this code atm. Hope that anybody can help me out with this one. Thanks a lot!

```
<?php
//connection info xxxx
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
//advertisement SELECT
$sql = "SELECT logo_fid FROM advertisement ORDER BY nid ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

//advertisement SELECT
$sql2 = "SELECT fid, filepath FROM files";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

if ($result->num_rows > 0 && $result2->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
  while(($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) && ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc())){

     //So after i received all the info i'd like to check if the value of logo_fid matches with fid and if so replace the value with the value of filepath
       if ($row["logo_fid"] == $row2["fid"]) :
       echo $row2["filepath"];
       else :
       echo $row["logo_fid"];
        endif;
       echo '<br>';



    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: I don;t know what the problem is since i dont know how to program my request. Thats why i described my request.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this could be done as one query.

```
SELECT A.logo_Fid, F.Fid, F.filePath, coalesce(F.FilePath, Logo_Fid) as ValueYouWant
FROM advertisement A
LEFT JOIN files F
 on A.logo_Fid = F.FID
```

Then you can echo ValueYouWant without the inline logic.

The join relates the two tables on the Fid and logo_fid. 
if a match is found, Valueyouwant will contain the f.filepath, if no match is found logo_fid will be in valueyouwant.

Since this is using a LEFT join, all values from advertisement will be returned, and only related records from files will be returned.

so to display...

I don't do much PHP, but an online search that was accpted as an answer indicates it would be something like this...

```
 $sql="    SELECT A.logo_Fid, F.Fid, F.filePath, coalesce(F.FilePath, Logo_Fid) as ValueYouWant
    FROM advertisement A
    LEFT JOIN files F
     on A.logo_Fid = F.FID ORDER BY NID asc"

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo $row['ValueYouWant'];
 echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. So this comes down to: 
`//advertisement SELECT
$sql = "SELECT A.logo_Fid, F.Fid, F.filePath, coalesce(F.FilePath, Logo_Fid) as ValueYouWant
FROM advertisement A
LEFT JOIN files F
 on A.logo_Fid = F.FID";
$result = $conn->query($sql);` 
and then how exactly do I echo the ValueYouWant result? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again. Tried multiple things but didn't get anything returned. I did put a `;` at the end of the $sql. So something is not working. I saw that the table/column names in SELECT have capitals, is there a reason for that? I tried to make them match with the names in my mysql database, but that didn't make a difference. Thanks again!